# Function with the property $f(x)f(-x)<0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

> Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined such that the property $f(x)f(-x)<0$ holds for all $x \neq 0$.
>
> Also let $f(0) = a.$ Show that if $f$ is continuous at the origin, then $a=0$.

So assuming that $f$ is continuous at the origin we have that $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x) =f(0
)=a.$

I don't see how this would help here at all? Any tips on how to proceed?

Comment: What is $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}f(x)f(-x)$?

Comment: Note that either $f(x) > 0$ or $f(-x) > 0$ Also note that whichever one is positive, the other must be negative. What does this imply about the behavior near zero?

Comment: Hint: If $a > 0$, choose $\epsilon = a$ and apply the definition of limit to find an interval around $0$ on which $f > 0$.  Then for $x$ in this interval, $f(x), f(-x) >0$, so...

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that $f$ is continuous at the origin. Set $g(x)=f(x)f(-x)$ and note that this is a function that is continuous at the origin too. Observe that for $x\neq 0$ it is $g(x)<0$. Also, since $$\lim_{x\to0}g(x)=f(0)^2=a^2,$$
we have that $a^2\leq0$. This is only possible if $a=0$.